# Termination of program using if else statement?

Tags: java

trying to terminate program using negative numbers and  if else statement . does anyone see whats wrong with this thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    int n;
    int i=0;

    System.out.print("Enter a Number:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    n= scanner.nextInt();
    int backUp = n;
    if(n>0)

        n=n/10;
        i++;

        else if(backUp = -1)

        System.out.print("program terminated......");
            System.exit(0);



    System.out.println("Number of Digits in " +backUp +" is " +i);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use brackets around the if and else blocks `{` and `}`

Comment: I wonder why you don't use IDE 'cause it seems your code couldn't be even compiled successfully. I see you asked what's wrong with it..so compiler would answer :) and then we could discuss the logic.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `=` is for assigning values. Use `==` for comparing.

Also, you need to use `{}` after `if` and `else` statements if you want to run more than one line.

Comment: @javaBeginner It is. If you look at the `if(n>0)` part, only the very next line will be dependent on the `if` statement, the next line (`i++`) will *always* execute, then the `else if` will result in a syntax error because it's not immediately after an if statement.

Comment: Without {} the else has no meaning. And I think `System.exit(0)` should be called when exiting. (-1)

Comment: i mean to say that when user enters any value greater than 0 then it will be terminated

Comment: @javaBeginner The intention seems to be that the user entering `-1` will result in the program terminating, but any other input wouldn't.

Comment: @javaBeginner While technically you may be correct, it is always good practice to wrap your `if` statements in `{}`, prevents silly mistakes like the one presented - IMHO

Answer (score 4):

```
   else if(backUp =  -1)
```

Should be

```
   else if(backUp == -1)
```

=    assignment operator ,  `==`  is for comparing

And finally  with missed `{}`

```
  if (n > 0) {
            n = n / 10;
            i++;
   } else if (backUp == -1) {
            System.out.print("program terminated......");
            System.exit(0);
   }else{
          // do something else. I have no idea. 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `{ }` for your `if`-statements. In `if` statements without the `{ }`, only  the line following the if-statement will be affected by the outcome of the `if-test`.

So:

```
if (condition)
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
```

will execute `doSomething()` if `condition == true` and `doSomethingElse()` no matter if `condition == true`.

```
if (condition) {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

will execute both `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()`, if and only if condition == true.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an assignment operator to evaluate a condition.

```
else if(backUp = -1)
```

should be

```
else if(backup == -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `else` use `if(backup==-1).`

Comment: There is a difference between `if` and `if else`.

Comment: @AnubhavSharma Then tell him what the proper syntax is, don't tell him to completely change the way his code will execute.

Comment: it should be like this...if(n>0)
{
    n=n/10;
    i++;
}
    else if(backUp == -1)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your indenting.

Secondly, if you want to execute multiple statements given a certain condition you'll need to put it in a code block like `if(x) { /* do multiple things */ }`.

Thirdly, your `else if(backUp = -1)` is invalid because you need a boolean expression inside a if, `backUp = -1` is an assignment and thus does not evaluate to a boolean (you probably want backUp == -1).

And you probably want to loop the `n = n/10; i++;` part because now it will never count more than 1 digit.